# try/catch vs if/else throwing NullPointerException

Tags: java, if-statement, exception, try-catch, null-pointer

What would I choose when you want to throw a NullPointerException?

1)

```
if(parameter != null){
  // do something
} else {
  Log.error("Reason for Exception.");
  throw new NullPointerException();
}
```

2)

```
try{
  // do something
} catch (NullPointerException npe) {
  Log.error("Reson for Exception.");
  throw npe;
}
```

Comment: None, I would throw an `IllegalArgumentException`, but I prefer the first one

Comment: honestly... i´d never would want to manually fire a `NPE`, if it´s a method i´d rather throw an `IllegalArgumentException` there.

Comment: [Effective Java](https://books.google.hr/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA248&lpg=PA248&dq=effective+java+standard+exceptions&source=bl&ots=yZJoQmw0M0&sig=8BlDhQjQqy3g41tQCCS2Znuk_T8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi1-sqiub7QAhXKIsAKHWNXBaAQ6AEIPzAG#v=onepage&q&f=false) advises the NPE, but I'm also on Kevin and Pau's side.

Comment: The other thing here is that you shouldn't log and rethrow. This potentially leads to multiple messages for the same exception. If you're throwing, just throw it. If you want to add extra info about the reason, throw a new exception with the message.

Answer (score 3):

In 2) you won't know exactly which expression threw the NPE. In 1) it is perfectly clear why you're throwing the exception. If necessary, have a number of separate null checks.

However, your first approach should be rewritten:

```
if (arg == null) {
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("arg is null");
}
... just go on with the method, no else block needed
```

And if you're at least on Java 7:

```
Objects.requireNonNull(arg, "arg is null");
```

A second point: the general rule is to either throw an exception or log an error, never both at the same time. In this case you should choose to throw, and there should be just one central place, covering the whole unit of work, where all exceptions are caught and logged.

Comment: but what do i do when adding the if/else in method that has a return value? (some specific object) what do I return in that case that will make sure that there has been an error?

Comment: When you throw an exception, you don't return anything.

Comment: right, i know, but you said i shouldn't throw an exception when logging...

Comment: You shouldn't _log_, just throw.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would use `IllegalArgumentException` over `NullPointerException` in this case. But in the case of choose between both, I prefer the first one just because it's clear.

Otherwise, to avoid boilerplate code like this, which in my opinion makes it ugly. I would use an `Assert` class which checks it. You could do your own Assert class or use some which are done, like Spring `Assert` and so on.

Your `Assert` class would be something like this:

```
public Assert {

    public static void isNotNull(Object object) {
          if(null == object) 
              throw new IllegalArgumentException(".. must be not null");
    }

    ....

}
```

Then you just need to use it like that (it reduces the boilperplate code to one line):

```
Assert.isNotNull(parameter);
```

Comment: It's in the JDK: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: Why would you use a less specific exception over a more specific exception?

Answer (score 1):

The first code looks appropriate since you've already tested the value and can give a result of null when failing the if condition.

Answer (score -1):

If you're trying to verify a parameter is not null I would recommend [Guava's Preconditions](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/PreconditionsExplained), specifically checkNotNull.

```
Preconditions.checkNotNull(parameter, "Please specify a value for parameter");
```

If parameter is null it throws a NPE with the message specified.